# Why does my `print` work both with and without `str`?

Tags: python, calculator

```
if islem == "+":
    print("sonuç: "+str(ilksayı+ikincisayı))

elif islem == "-":
    print("sonuç: "+ str(ilksayı-ikincisayı))

elif islem == "x":
    print("sonuç: "+ str(ilksayı*ikincisayı))

elif islem == "/":
    print("sonuç: "+ (ilksayı/ikincisayı))
```

as you see first second and third if and elif codes are with str but last one don't have str and this is the question: whats difference str and nothing (codes are working both of them)

im learning from a video and teacher use str but i dont get the difference can someone explain?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: It's proper to call str(), but since you are concatenating a strings + something else, the second may be converted to string automatically. In other words, you don't need to explicitly set str(). As @furas pointed out, `"Age: " + 10` will result in an error. Do note that in other languages other than python, this automatic conversion may not happen.

Comment: frankly, you could use comma `,` in `print` to send it as second argument and it will convert it to string automatically `print("sonuç:", ilksayı/ikincisa )`

Comment: Please do not use a title of "can someone help me". That is not going to be useful to future users of the site who may have the same question as you.

Comment: @sleepystar96 in Python `str + int` gives error message `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: How do you know your code works?

Comment: @furas ah you're right my bad. I'll amend my answer. Thanks

Comment: @slothrop, I was wrong, perhaps using string.format, like `f"Age: {10}"` would be better than concatenating with the + operator.

Comment: @sleepystar96 right, but your comment seems contradictory. You say *"since you are concatenating a strings + something else, the second may be converted to string automatically"* And we just established that it is **not** converted to string automatically?

Comment: @slothrop You're right, can't edit my comment anymore sadly. Straight from `builtins.pyi` this is the overload for the `__add__ `operator:   `def __add__(self, __value: str) -> str: ...`, the second arg is expected to be str or LiteralString.

Comment: Possibly, you've mis-interpreted the error.  The last _print_ call there, should produce a _TypeError_.  For example, _"print('a / b = ' + (a / b))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"_.

Comment: On a side note, instead of multiple if else statements, you might want to use operator class to do the operation
`import operator

operator_dic = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    'x': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv
}


print("sonuç:", operator_dic[islem](ilksayı, ikincisayı))`

Answer (score 1):

`str(ilksayı*ikincisayı)` converts the result of (ilksayı*ikincisayı) to a string whilst `(ilksayı/ikincisayı)` leaves the result in it's original data type.

*NOTE* You cannot concatenate (+) a string to a non-string.